# How to write page specific CSS in backbone js

Tags: css, backbone.js

I have backbone application and wanted to write custom css applicable only for a particular page. Something like how we write in `<style></style>` tags in html pages. Is there a way to write similar code in the corresponding dust files in backbone js. I don't want to dynamically add css file in the view js files, because my page specific css will be one or two lines and it is different for every page.

**EDIT:**

I have jq editor as shown below and it gets rendered dynamically(hence, cannot write inline css) and it is used in multiple pages across my application and I want to control its height, width and other properties in a particular page. That is why I need write page specific css, this page is written in backbone js (.dust, view.js and model.js).
[image]

Comment: I think you need a packer like webpack, can u show a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my page specific css will be one or two lines and it is different for every page

Since it's small, I don't think there will be a problem with loading this CSS before hand via a css file.

You can simply have a selector for each page and specify the CSS like:

```
#page1 .editor{
/*^---unique selector of page*/
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
}
#page2 .editor{
/*--------^---selector of editor*/
  height:80%;
  width:60%;
}
```